# Beamer Graphics driving me nuts

Tags: beamer

I am using the theme here:
http://cameron.bracken.bz/beamer-template

When I include a figure as:

```
\begin{frame}{frame 2}
\includegraphics[scale=.2]{beta_1.eps}
\end{frame}
```

and run pdfLatex, I get the following error:

```
! Latex Error: unknown graphics extension .eps
```

What is going on and how do I fix this? I am using WinEdt as the front end and I am on a windows machine. The picture is in the same folder as the source file and there are no typos etc. Compiles as "Latex" and "Texify", but I don't see the bubbles on the heading bar.

Comment: pdflatex can not by default include eps files (nothing to do with beamer) It is best not to put the extension in the includegraphics call then latex just looks for the versions it can use, eg convert the eps to pdf and pdflatex can include it

Comment: With `pdflatex` you can't use `eps` directly. Change the graphics format to `pdf`, `png` or `jpg`.

Comment: I have about 70-80 figures man...what else can I do? I just want the heading bar to be preserved. Doing a dvi->pdf does not preserve it.

Comment: There are packages that will call but it shouldn't really matter how many files there are you should be able to do something like `for %f  in (*.eps) do \imagemagic\convert %f %f.pdf`

Comment: With an up-to-date TeX system, EPS graphics will automatically be converted to PDF format: all you need to do is _not_ include the extension.

Comment: Joseph, tried your suggestion, it does not work. Before I start I usually manually update MikTex. Thanks to everybody else who replied. Looks like I have no choice but to mass convert all my eps figures to pdf.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to convert all eps files into pdf files using a batch programm such like `eps2pdf` ([CTAN link](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/eps2pdf/)).

Then you can use `pdflatex`.